# How to recognize captcha text from an image in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm using `PyTesseract` and `Pillow` to `OCR` text from an image. But unfortunately, no matter how I try, I can’t accurately recognize the text from 2 pictures. Here is my code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

captcha_image = Image.open('1.jpg')

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(captcha_image)
captcha_image = enhancer.enhance(2)

captcha_image = captcha_image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())

captcha_image = captcha_image.convert('L')

captcha_image = captcha_image.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 200 else 255, '1')

captcha_image = captcha_image.resize((captcha_image.width * 3, captcha_image.height * 3), Image.BICUBIC)

captcha_image.save('res.jpg')

captcha_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(captcha_image)

print(captcha_text)
```

When trying to recognize text from 1 captcha, it recognizes 2 letters incorrectly, most likely due to their slope (Recognized as "2X WIL"):

[image]

And it recognizes the second captcha as "DCXN", in some cases it doesn't recognize it at all:

[image]

I am hope for your help!

Comment: "But unfortunately, no matter how I try, I can’t accurately recognize the text"  Isn't that the whole purpose of a captcha?

Comment: you can try to deskew the image to straighten the text, `deskew` library can help with that. also, instead of using a fixed threshold (like 200 in your code), sometimes using adaptive thresholding can give better results as it considers the neighborhood pixels.